# Can I see on the application that the app_remove event is triggered in my Android application?

Tags: android, firebase, uninstallation, android-package-managers

Is there a way to catch the **app_remove** event fired in my Android app? In any way, when the application is **uninstalled**, there is data that I need to delete from the device during uninstallation. Is there any way I can do this with **firebase** **app_remove** or otherwise?

What I mean by data here is that the user makes some settings on his phone together with the application. I need to get these settings back as soon as the app is deleted. Storage has nothing to do with it.

Comment: When an Android app is uninstalled, all of its local storage is deleted along with it. What do you need to delete that you somehow managed to store outside that space, which probably required special permissions or collaboration with another app or service?

Comment: @DougStevenson What I mean by data here is that the user makes some settings on his phone together with the application. I need to get these settings back as soon as the app is deleted. Storage has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It might be helpful if you are more specific about what you're trying to do. There could be other options that you're not considering.  Firebase Analytics isn't the right choice for triggering anything at all in your app.  It's just for data collection.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to catch the app_remove event fired in my android app?

No, sorry.

> when the application is uninstalled, there is data that I need to delete from the device during uninstallation

Store the data in locations that will be cleaned up automatically when the app is uninstalled. That includes locations obtained from `Context`, such as `getFilesDir()`, `getCacheDir()`, and `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Comment: actually it is not related to the storage I mentioned as data. There are things I need to change regarding the phone's settings set. Somehow, when the user deletes the application, I need to delete the settings he set with the application.

Comment: @HasanKucuk: That is not an option, sorry.